Trouble installing OOT modules for GNU-Radio in windows 10 with miniforge3
I install GNU Radio in windows, and I'm trying to install gr-paint OOT modules using conda with miniforge3. I've followed every step on the github of gr-paint.
But the last step ( conda build .conda recipe -m %CONDA_PREFIX% conda_build_config.yaml) is the one I'm having trouble with. When I run the previous command this is the prompt I get, and got no clue what is wrong with it (any kind of help is welcomed):
An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
If you suspect this error is being caused by a malfunctioning plugin, consider using the --no-plugins option to turn off plugins.
Example: conda --no-plugins install 
Alternatively, you can set the CONDA_NO_PLUGINS environment variable on the command line to run the command without plugins enabled.
Example: CONDA_NO_PLUGINS=true conda install 
If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?
I was trying to install and begin to use gr-paint in order to use the specific blocks from gr-paint in GNU Radio.
